# Prolog recursion - why do I need to declare an extra variable

Tags: prolog

One thing I don't understand is why must we declare another variable during recursion. For example:

```
fact(0,1).
fact(N,M):- N>0, N1 is N-1, M is M1 * N, fact(N1, M1).
```

Why can't we just do:

```
fact(0,1).
fact(N,M):- N>0, M is M1 * N, fact(N - 1, M1).
```

On certain recursions, the latter will give a stack overflow error. What is the difference between the 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to Lisp -- or almost any "conventional" programming language -- you need to explicitly quote things to prevent them from being executed. Prolog is the opposite: everything is implicitly quoted and you need to explicitly mark things that are executable, either by them being a goal or by being the argument to a predicate that interprets (evaluates) them.

So, let's look at your 2nd clause:

```
fact(N,M):- 
    N>0,              % 1
    M is M1 * N,      % 2
    fact(N - 1, M1).  % 3
```

In item #1, `N>0` (which is the same as `'>'(N,0)`) is in an executable context (a *goal* on the right-hand side) and therefore the predicate `'>'/2` is called (more on this later).

In item #2, `M is M1 * N` is the same as `is(M, '*'(M1,N))` ... the `is(...,...)` is in an executable context but the `M1*N` is not: it's just a structure (or "term"). The `is/2` predicate *interprets* the 2nd argument and unifies the result with the 1st argument.

In item #3, it's similar -- equivalent to `fact('-'(N,1), M1)` -- and the `'-'(N,1)` is a structure that isn't interpreted further. So, `N-1` will be passed as an uninterpreted argument (the `N1` will, of course` be whatever value that it's been instantiated to).

Now, the confusing part is that the `'>'/2` predicate *interprets* its arguments. So, if it gets called, for example, with `1+2 > 0`, it interprets the `1+2` (resulting in `3`) and also the `0` (resulting in `0`) and then does the comparison.

Here's another way of defining `fact/2`, which might make things clearer:

```
fact(N, 1) :- 0 is N . % Need is/2 to force evaluation of N
fact(N, Fac) :- 
    N > 0,         % evaluates N 
    fact(N-1, F0), % does *not* evaluate N-1 
    Fac = N*F0.    % does *not* evaluate N*F0 ... Fac is N*F0 would evaluate
```

And this query:

```
?- fact(3,X), X2 is X.
X = 3*((3-1)*((3-1-1)*1)),
X2 = 6 .
```

You might find it instructive to try the query `trace, fact(2,X)`; and also change the last goal (`Fac = N*F0`) to `Fac is N*F0`.

Comment: For a more efficient version, it is better to replace `fat(N-1, F0)` with `N1 is N-1, fat(N1,F0)`.

Comment: My code was not intended to be efficient - it's to illustrate a point about terms being (generally) unevaluated. Even more efficient would be to use an accumulator.